# Definite integral problem of $\frac{x^n}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, recreational-mathematics, gamma-function, fractional-calculus

I want to evaluate the following definite integral.

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}dn$$

Where we have $n!=\Gamma(n+1)=\int_0^\infty t^ne^{-t}dt$ so that we can have $n\in\mathbb{R}$.

I don't think there is a solution to this, but I do note that

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}dn\sim\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}=e^x$$

Also, we define $0^0=1$.

The context to this problem is that I want to see if

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^nf^{(n)}(a)}{n!}dn=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^nf^{(n)}(a)}{n!}$$

A modification to Taylor's theorem for fractional calculus.

Under my conditions, it is obvious that the two are equal for $x=0$, but even for the seemingly trivial case of $x=1$, I don't know how to solve the integral.

WolframAlpha provides a series representation for the indefinite integral ($x=1$), but I am unsure if I can even use it.

Feel free to tackle just the $x=1$ case.  From graphing, it seems very possible that $\int_0^\infty\frac1{n!}dn=e$, but I'm not fully sure.

From [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%200%20to%20100%201%2F(x!)), I have found that $\int_0^\infty\frac1{n!}d\approx2.2665$.

**EDIT**

Numerical calculations say $\int_{-\gamma}^\infty\frac1{n!}dn\approx2.70907$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.  It seems very close to $e$...

Comment: Indeed it doesn't. That $\;dn\;$ can be very confusing, in particula if you *also* use $\;x\;$ in the integrand. Also, you must use the generalization of the factorial by means of the Gamma function, or whatever, otherwise you have there only a discrete variable and I can't see how to properly integrate that.

Comment: @Joanpemo I'm sorry, was just how I had it going... So, why does it diverge?  The summation converges and $x^n$ grows much slower than $n!$, assuming $x>-1$ to avoid a problematic singularity.  And I did mention the gamma function.  It was just easier to write the factorial everywhere.  Should I change it?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I was agreeing with you about not diverging. And you mentioned the Gamma function but, unless I misunderstood something, only for natural $\;n\;$, and we still have a discrete variable.

Comment: @Joanpemo My intention is indeed for $n\in\mathbb{R}$, I don't want it to be discrete...  :/

Comment: Thank you, I think I got it this time.

Comment: [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351423/an-analogue-of-the-exponential-function-by-replacing-infinite-series-with-improp) on the same integral

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there's a closed form, but you can write it as

$$ \int_0^1 \sum_{j=0}^\infty \dfrac{x^{a+j}}{\Gamma(a+j+1)}\; da = 
\int_0^1 e^x \left(1 - \dfrac{a \Gamma(a,x)}{\Gamma(a+1)}\right)\; da $$

Numerically, the value at $x=1$ is approximately $2.266534508$.

Comment: I do wish it were equal to $e$, that would have been far more interesting.

Comment: Note that your integral simplifies down to:$$\int_0^1 e^x P(a,x) dx$$, P(a,x) is a [Regularized Lower Incomplete  Gamma function](https://www.wikidoc.org/index.php/Regularized_Gamma_function). This is just a [truncated exponential function](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/GammaRegularized/06/01/05/01/02/0004/) Taylor Series for $x\in\Bbb N$. The upper function, Q(a,z), is related by: $$P(a,z)+Q(a,z)=1$$.